# deserializing a list of objects json object with jackson - cannot deserialize instance out of start_array token

Tags: java, json, jackson, mapping

I am reading a JSON response back from Mailchimp's Mandrill API with jackson. The response is a bit unconventional for an API response in that it includes handlebars inside of square brackets - a list of objects. The other stack overflow discussions around this error pertain to API responses that are not in a list.

```
[
    {
        "email": "gideongrossman@gmail.com",
        "status": "sent",
        "_id": "6c6afbd3702f4fdea8de690c284f5898",
        "reject_reason": null
    }
]
```

I am getting this error...

```
2019-07-06 22:41:47.916 DESKTOP-2AB6RK0 core.RestClient 131222 ERROR com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `core.user.MandrillWrapper$TemplatedEmailResponse` out of START_ARRAY token
```

What is the correct way to define this response object?

I have tried defining the response with the following types. None worked.

```
public static class TemplatedEmailResponse {
    public LinkedHashMap<String, String>[] response;
}




public static class TemplatedEmailResponse {
    public ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> response;
}
```

@milchalk...How exactly can I use your objectmapper suggestion with the way I am currently calling the API and handling the response?

```
TemplatedEmailResponseList ret = getClient("messages/send-template.json").post(mandrillPayload,
            TemplatedEmailResponseList.class);
```

where

```
public <T> T post(Object payload, Class<T> responseType) {
    try {
        Entity<Object> entity = Entity.entity(payload, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        T t = client.target(url).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(entity, responseType);
        return t;
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        logError(t);
        throw t;
    } finally {
        client.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can deserialize this json directly to `List` of your Pojo classes.

Given model class :

```
public class TemplatedEmailResponse {
    private String email;
    private String status;
    private String _id;
    private String reject_reason;
    //getters setters
}
```

You can deserialize this json using TypeReference for `List<TemplatedEmailResponse>` :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
TypeReference<List<TemplatedEmailResponse>> typeRef = new TypeReference<List<TemplatedEmailResponse>>() {};
List<TemplatedEmailResponse> list = mapper.readValue(json, typeRef);
```

Where `json` variable represents the json string in this case.

Comment: Cheers! I edited my question to ask for clarification on your answer.